# Remind users to reset password, but don't actually expire them

Tags: passwords, exchange, active-directory, exchange-2007

A client is running exchange 2007. They have passwords that reset every 90 days, with the reminder set at 7 days.

What keeps happening is that users dismiss the reminder, and forget their password is going to expire, then when it does, they're usually not in the office, and trying to connect remotely via VPN (uses same credentials as exchange), or on a mobile device.

I'm looking at the default group policy at these settings, is there a way to remind the user every 7 days to reset (after the max password time has passed), but don't actually expire the password?

Comment: Active Domain doesn't have this capability.  It would also be a worthless capability since it would be basically broken a security feature.

Comment: Not worthless. Nagging people go reset every will make them reset it to get rid of the annoying messages. Currently, it nags them once, then locks their account, where they can't do anything apart from call up IT to fix it. It also puts the blame on the user, and not on IT by using this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think there is a built in feature that you can use from a gpo to do what you want.
i would suggest you create a small vbs script that checks days until the password expires and then shows a message or something and run that script from a logon script.

you can use a gpo to run scripts at logon.